# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component theme provider

Tags: javascript, react-native, themes

I need help because I get the following error: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method. in createCategory (at themeProvider.js:39)

```
/* Imports */
    import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
    import THEMES from '@app/theme/themes.json';
    /* /Imports/ */

    const STORAGE_KEY = 'THEME_ID';
    const ThemeContext = React.createContext();

    /* Exports */
    export const ThemeContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
      const [themeID, setThemeID] = useState();

      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          const storedThemeID = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
          if (storedThemeID) setThemeID(storedThemeID);
          else setThemeID(THEMES[1].key);
        })();
      }, []);

      return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ themeID, setThemeID }}>
          {!!themeID ? children : null}
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
      );
    };

    export function withTheme(Component) {
      function TargetComponent(props) {
        const { themeID, setThemeID } = useContext(ThemeContext);
        const getTheme = themeID => THEMES.find(theme => theme.key === themeID);
        const setTheme = themeID => {
          AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, themeID);
          setThemeID(themeID);
        };

        return (
          <Component
            {...props}
            themes={THEMES}
            theme={getTheme(themeID)}
            setTheme={setTheme}
          />
        );
      }

      TargetComponent.navigationOptions = Component.navigationOptions;

      return TargetComponent;
      }
    /* /Exports/ */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't already know - you can return a function at the end of your useEffect hook. That function will be called whenever that effect is fired again (e.g. when the values of its dependencies have changed), as well as right before the component unmounts. So if you have a useEffect hook that looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // logic here

  return () => {
    // clean up
  };
}, []); // no dependencies!
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // logic here
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // clean up
  }
}
```

So in your code I'd add this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let isCancelled = false;
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      // fetch logic omitted...
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);

      if (storedThemeID) setThemeID(storedThemeID);
      else setThemeID(THEMES[1].key);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e)
    }
  };

  fetchData();

  return () => {
    isCancelled = true;
  };
}, [themeID]);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202440/discussion-on-answer-by-jurrian-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmount).

Comment: Can you look our discussion?

Comment: Did you see that?

Comment: I've send you a message on monday.

Comment: Yes. I look it and just that is ur link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

Comment: Please I need the fix to end of the weekend

Comment: What's up? I need your help.

Comment: Tomorrow I have time, I'll send a chat

Comment: Okey. I wait u today.

Comment: Did you send a chat?

Comment: Yes, look at the chat.

Comment: Look at the chat.

Comment: Jurran. Did you fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let unmounted = false;

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const storedThemeID = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
        if (!unmounted) {
            if (storedThemeID) setThemeID(storedThemeID);
            else setThemeID(THEMES[1].key);
        }
    })();
    return () => {
        unmounted = true;
    };
}, []);
```